# ng-Click() is not working

Tags: angularjs

This issue is on the button click.

controller'

```
$scope.sendQuery = function(queryString){
      $scope.query=queryString;    
};
```

View

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" data-ng-model="queryString">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendQuery(queryString)" type="button">Send Query</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
```

This was worked fine previously.but suddenly it is not working.can anyone see mistakes here?
Thanks

Comment: Can you see any errors in your console ?

Comment: if that is all the code then it must work, i don't find any mistake there.or mistake might be somewhere else

Comment: have you define your controller as well?

Comment: @Arjun indeed with that code, it's not displaying something, but it's working well ^^

Comment: @MSKP all of 3 answers provided are correctly working, please check them and tell us if you did expect this behavior

Comment: Thanks everyone.now its working :D i didn't debugged it correctly.that's the reason.the code i put here also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass your ng-model in your function. It will be available otherwise too in the controller since its in the same scope.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.sendQuery = function(){
      $scope.query=$scope.queryString;   
      console.log($scope.query);
};
```

**Working Fiddle** :http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11798/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expected, but I wrote a Plunkr that set the `input text` in *$scope* and display it when the button is pressed.

https://plnkr.co/edit/4vVWqWUiKYzV7FUcZ7yL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Check this below snippent

```js
angular.module('sample',[]).controller('sampleController',['$scope', function($scope)
{
$scope.sendQuery = function(queryString){
      $scope.query= queryString;  
      alert($scope.query)
};
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='sample'  ng-controller='sampleController' class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="queryString">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendQuery(queryString)" type="button">Send Query</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
```